# JavaScript - Check if one array has the same index from a second array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an object of

```
var people = [
  {name: 'John'}, // 0
  {name: 'James'}, // 1
  {name: 'Sue'}, // 2
  {name: 'Mary'}, // 3
  {name: 'Will'}, // 4
  {name: 'Lukas'}, // 5
  {name: 'Sam'} // 6
];
```

and then I have this array: `var history = [0, 2, 4, 6]; // we have John, Sue, Will and Sam`

Using Lodash, or general JavaScript, how can I make it to return `true` or `false` if a entered value is found inside the `history[]` array.

For example, `isInHistoryArray(5)` would return `false` but `isInHistoryArray(2)` would return `true`

Comment: Maybe you mean array comparing, check this [answer1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript), [answer2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020551/how-to-compare-elements-in-an-array-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

You have list-array of players in the small game:

```
var people = [
  {name: 'John'},
  {name: 'James'},
  {name: 'Sue'},
  {name: 'Mary'},
  {name: 'Will'},
  {name: 'Lukas'},
  {name: 'Sam'}
];
```

And you have array of the... actually connected people:

```
var history = [0, 2, 4, 6];
```

Okay, lets say that both containers are in the global scope for comfort.

You can check it by this function body

```
function checkHistory(a){
for(var i = 0; i < history.length; i++){
   if(history[i] === a) return true;
}return false;}
```

Comment: Bacause it can be modded to make it automatic from any other data and returning auto name of record or sth.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `[includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)' method

```
history.includes(5) // false
history.includes(0) // true
```

Comment: Arrays have no `includes` method (yet), just strings. `history` is an array.

Comment: `Array#includes` is a Stage 4 ES2016 proposal, which V8 implements. It's not broadly available yet, nor is the spec completed. It **should** be in the spec when it comes out, Stage 4 means "ready to include in the spec," but you need a cutting-edge JavaScript engine (or a polyfill) to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have an [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method that compares what you give it against the entries in the array (using strict comparison, `===`) and tells you the index of the first match, or -1 (specifically) if there is no match. So:

```
function isInHistoryArray(value) {
    return history.indexOf(value) !== -1;
}
```

In ES2015, there are also `Array.find` and `Array.findIndex` (both of which can be polyfilled on older engines) that let you supply a predicate callback, but you don't need that here as your entries are numbers and what you're checking is also a number.