# How can the first element be compared to the rest of the elements and the second element to the rest of the elements and the same repetition

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, for-loop, string-literals

I want compare between elements in the same array to get this result

```js
      let arr = ['one','two','three','four'];
      arr.forEach((ele, i, ar)=>{
      console.log(ele, i, ar)
      for(let item = i; item< ar.length; item++ ){
        console.log (ele, ar[item])
      }
    })
```

```
    'one' => 'two',
    'one' => 'three',
    'one' => 'four',
    'two' => 'three',
    'two' => 'four',
    'three' => 'four'.
```

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: try researching before posting, this is a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare elements in an array (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020551/how-to-compare-elements-in-an-array-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two for loop, and make the second loop start from the index of the first loop + 1:

```js
let arr = ['one','two','three','four'];


for(let i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
  for(j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
    console.log(arr[i],' => ', arr[j]);
  }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response
I want this result while deleting the duplicate result

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you explain better what you need?

Comment: one  =>  one
one  =>  two
one  =>  three
one  =>  four
two  =>  two
two  =>  three
two  =>  four
three  =>  three
three  =>  four
four  =>  four
-------------------------
i want to remove 
-------------------------------
one  =>  one,
two  =>  two
three  =>  three
four  =>  four

Comment: I updated the answer, it should be what you want now

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatMap` and `slice`

```js
let arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

const res = arr.flatMap((x, i) => arr.slice(i + 1).map(y => `${x} => ${y}`));

console.log(res)
```